# Merge exes in installer, and make it autorun

Tags: windows, merge, installation, autorun

I use linux, and have moderate windows experience.

What I would like to do is merge

```
 a.exe 
 b.exe
```

into one installer.
And want the installer to run first a.exe, make it autorun on startup.
Then immediatly run "b".
So b.exe is placed somwhere, with "a", but "a" is autorun on startup.

What would be the smart way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand the requirement to *merge* them. Why not just install both executables, set up `a.exe` to autorun on startup, and have `a.exe` launch `b.exe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use WinRAR for this and create self-extracting archive, with autorun program setting enabled which will run prepared `bat` file. I know you said you use Linux, but it's not impossible with wine, especially when you're working with `exe` files  ;)